How do I prevent updating of a view in a timer from clearing SwiftUI popoverTips?
I have a SwiftUI app for iOS that includes a message area. Each time the app displays a message, a timer is set to clear it a few seconds later. The message is stored in an observable string that SwiftUI displays in a Text view.
The app also includes popoverTips from SwiftUI's TipKit.
If a popoverTip is visible when a timer fires and clears the message, the popoverTip unexpectedly closes. I expect it to remain open. It does not matter if the popoverTip obscures the message in the UI or not.
Oddly, the last popoverTip to open does not automatically close. It remains open, as expected, when a timer fires. In a sample app that has three popoverTips, it does not matter which of the three popoverTips is the last to open. Whichever is last remains open.
In my sample app, each of the three buttons updates a message in the UI, and opens a popoverTip for another button. When the timer fires to clear the message, the popoverTip closes, but only if the popoverTip is not the third to open. I expect all popoverTips to remain open.
If I invalidate the timer before opening a popoverTip, the popoverTip remains open, albeit at the expense of the message not clearing.
How do I prevent my timer from clearing my popoverTips?
import SwiftUI
import TipKit

final class Message: ObservableObject {
    var timer: Timer?
    @Published var message = " "
    func invalidate() -> Void {
        timer?.invalidate()
    }
    func say(_ text: String) -> Void {
        timer?.invalidate()
        message = text
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2.5, repeats: false) { _ in
            self.message = " "  // oddly, also closes a tip other than the last tip.
        }
    }
}

struct HelloTip: Tip {
    @Parameter static var isShowTip: Bool = false
    var rules: [Rule] {
        #Rule(Self.$isShowTip) {
            $0 == true
        }
    }
    var title: Text {
        Text("Tip")
    }
    var message: Text? {
        Text("Tap to say hello.")
    }
}

struct StayTip: Tip {
    @Parameter static var isShowTip: Bool = false
    var rules: [Rule] {
        #Rule(Self.$isShowTip) {
            $0 == true
        }
    }
    var title: Text {
        Text("Tip")
    }
    var message: Text? {
        Text("Tap to say stay.")
    }
}

struct GoodbyeTip: Tip {
    @Parameter static var isShowTip: Bool = false
    var rules: [Rule] {
        #Rule(Self.$isShowTip) {
            $0 == true
        }
    }
    var title: Text {
        Text("Tip")
    }
    var message: Text? {
        Text("Tap to say goodbye.")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var message = Message()
    var helloTip = HelloTip()
    var stayTip = StayTip()
    var goodbyeTip = GoodbyeTip()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(message.message)
            
            Button("Say Hello") {
                message.say("Hello")
                //message.invalidate()
                StayTip.isShowTip.toggle()      // display tip for stay button
            }
            .popoverTip(helloTip)
            .padding(80)

            Button("Say Stay") {
                message.say("Stay")
                //message.invalidate()
                GoodbyeTip.isShowTip.toggle()   // display tip for goodbye button
            }
            .popoverTip(stayTip)
            .padding(.bottom, 80)

            Button("Say Goodbye") {
                message.say("Goodbye")
                //message.invalidate()
                HelloTip.isShowTip.toggle()     // display tip for hello button
            }
            .popoverTip(goodbyeTip)
        }
        .task {
            try? Tips.resetDatastore()
            try? Tips.configure([
                .displayFrequency(.immediate),
                .datastoreLocation(.applicationDefault)
            ])
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

Screenshot of sample app

My workaround is to invalidate the timer and clear the message before displaying a popoverTip.
